# Net Core 3.1 Entity Framework: Get all records where a property is NOT included

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In my Net Core 3.1 project I have the following model:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id {get; set;
    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    public bool IsMainTeam { get; set; }

    // relation with AppUser, the owner of the team
    public string OwnerId { get; set; }
    public AppUser Owner { get; set; }

    // navigational planes for m2m with users
    public ICollection<TeamsAppUsers> Members { get; set; }

}


public class TeamsAppUsers
{
    public Guid AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser Member { get; set; }

    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class AppUser
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public Guid ExtendedAppUserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The relation to the user's extended profile.
    /// </summary>
    public ExtendedAppUser ExtendedProfile {get; set;}

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of teams this user is a member of.
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<TeamsAppUsers> TeamsAppusers { get; private set; }

}
```

I want to write a query where all the teams are returned where the provided userId is not the OwnerId and not in the list of members (so, AppUserId in TeamAppUsers is not equal to the provided userId). Basically, all the teams should be returned where the user has nothing to do with...

What I had is something like this, but it doesn't do the trick:

```
var teams = await _context.Teams
    .Include(t => t.Owner)
    .Include(t => t.ExtendedTeamProfile)
    .Include(t => t.Members)
    .Where(t => t.Members.Any(m => m.AppUserId != userGuid) || t.OwnerId != userGuid)                    
    .ToListAsync();
```

The filtering on the Members property seems to be the problem here, any help is welcome!

Edit: Obviously, as pointed out, the || operator should be &&. Closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all the teams are returned where the provided userId is not the OwnerId **and** not in the list of members (emphasis mine)

Yet in your code you used `||` (ie, or). Wouldn't you want something like this:

```cs
var teams = await _context.Teams
    .Include(t => t.Owner)
    .Include(t => t.ExtendedTeamProfile)
    .Where(t => !t.Members.Any(m => m.AppUserId == userGuid) && t.OwnerId != userGuid)                    
    .ToListAsync();
```

TLDR: a whole bunch of boolean negation issues.

Comment: Thnx, I had '&&' on my first run and I changed that after I noticed something was off in the results. But I cannot reproduce that anymore, now....weird. Maybe it wasn't the operator that caused the initial problem but something else my 1st query had in it. Anyways, this indeed fixes it.

Comment: When in doubt, Ef.Core can output the raw sql statement used which you can use to check against your actual db. I was about to ask for it when I noticed the problem directly.